# UITableView as UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

Tags: swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I would like to extend `UITableView` by adding a custom `UIPanGestureRecognizer`:

```swift
extension UITableView {

   func addCustomPanGestureRecognizer() {
        let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
        panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)

        // some additional setup
        // ...
    }

}
```

Since custom gesture recognizer interferes with scrolling, I tried to implement `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` with an optional requirement:

```swift
extension UITableView: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return otherGestureRecognizer == self.panGestureRecognizer
    }

}
```

...but it's not getting called at all, despite delegating to tableView (as shown above).

Also, Xcode displays a warning:

> Instance method 'gestureRecognizer(*:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'gestureRecognizer(*:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:)' of protocol 'UIGestureRecognizerDelegate'

To get rid of the warning, I tried adding `@objc` annotation before method definition, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, Xcode needed some additional help with finding an appropriate Objective-C method definition. To achieve this I had to provide method signature after `@objc` annotation:

```swift
extension UITableView: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @objc(gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:)
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return otherGestureRecognizer == self.panGestureRecognizer
    }

}
```

The warning is still displayed, but the method is being called properly.